# Azure AD B2C login page is slow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using the Azure AD B2C authentication for Angular SPA. For some reason the login takes around 10 secs to load, when I check the browser dev tool there are 2 request which take most of the time. Is there a way to optimize this load time.

- Open Id configuration endpoint - 3sec
- Authorize endpoint - 6sec

[Dev tools screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h28O8.png)

Comment: User flow or custom policy?

Comment: It is the user flow of type `Sign up and sign in (Recommended)`

Comment: Could you please share the Azure B2C created regions? Could you please test in the US regions and let us know the differences?

Comment: It was created in the region East US 2. It was much faster in US locations but very much slow in Indian Region.

Comment: Dev Tools screen for US clients https://www.screencast.com/t/MfJGXImxJUHr and for Indian clients https://www.screencast.com/t/fdqS6DjTwx

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Were you able to speed up the loading time?

Comment: No, we have moved to AWS Cognito. We didn't get much support from Azure on this and we are on a tight schedule to wait any further.

Comment: Our experience is also that B2Clogin.com is very slow.  It is like this for months and they are not looking at it. (/cc @Jit_MSFT ) Bhagavan reddy: check also: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/update-apps-using-azure-ad-b2c-to-new-redirect-b2clogincom/

Answer (score 0):

Please note that even if Azure AD B2C is considered as global service in the Azure cloud, users' profile data is stored in the specific region that you select during Azure AD B2C tenant creation.
Here is a diagram that shows how it works - *directory store* is hosted under the region you specified for the Azure AD B2C tenant:

[image]

*Additional latency is only encountered when the user has performed an authentication in a different region from which they had signed-up in. This is because, calls will be made **across regions** to reach the Directory Store where their profile lives to complete their authentication.*

To solve the problem with multiple regions and reduce the time, you can check [Azure Active Directory B2C global identity framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/azure-ad-b2c-global-identity-solutions).